# Pass request values using XmlHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have username and two other elements submitted from a form, i can get them by id in a ajax .js file. now i wish to pass these three elements to a php file. i can create three variables each assigned to new XmlHttpReqest, for eg. var XmlHttpusername=new XmlHttpRequest().

now how do i pass these three request values to that single php file in which i have to compare these three things in a database and generate a message as appropriate.
My code for ajax is as follow:

```
 function GetXmlHttpObject()
 {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
          {
// code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        return null;
 }

// User name function 
var XMLHttpUsername=false;
var XMLHttpSec_q=false;
var XMLHttpSec_a=false;
function UserAvail(resp)
{
   XMLHttpUsername=GetXmlHttpObject();   
   if (XMLHttpUsername==null)
   {
      alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
      return;
   }
   XMLHttpUsername.open("GET","checkUser.php?user="+resp,true);
   XMLHttpUsername.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (XMLHttpUsername.readyState==4 && XMLHttpUsername.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('userChange').innerHTML=XMLHttpUsername.responseText; 
      }  
   }
   XMLHttpUsername.send(null); 
}

function InputCheck(resp)
{
   XMLHttpUsername=GetXmlHttpObject();
   XMLHttpSec_q=GetXmlHttpObject();
   XMLHttpSec_a=GetXmlHttpObject(); 

   if (XMLHttpInputs==null||XMLHttpSec_a==null||XMLHttpSec_q==null){
     alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
      return;
     }
   XMLHttpSec_a.open("GET","checkUser.php?user="+user,true);
   XMLHttpSec_a.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if (XMLHttpSec_a.readyState==4 && XMLHttpUsername.status == 200){
      document.getElementById('submitMain').innerHTML=XMLHttpSec_a.responseText; 
   }  
  }
  XMLHttpSec_a.send(null); 
}
```

Comment: You should fix your title, it's not a question. Also don't use GET to send sensitive data..

Comment: Have you thought about using a framework to help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass each of the three values as parameters in a single AJAX request:

```
XMLHttpSec_a.open("GET","checkUser.php?parameter1=" + parameter1 + "&parameter2=" + parameter2 + "&parameter3=" + parameter3);
```

There is no need to create separate requests for the sole purpose of sending multiple pieces of data.

Comment: You should use `encodeURIComponent()` to ensure that the parameters are properly encoded if they contain special characters.

Comment: The caller would have taken care of this if you are simply passing the query string on through Ajax.